# Code to check if cell names are the same in excel

Tags: excel

I have 16 different datasets and 112 different variables in each dataset but I would like to know if there is any function to check if the variables match in each dataset.

I have the variables copied into a new spreadsheet row wise on top of each other.
Can someone please tell me a code that would print a "*" next to each cell that does 
not match up with the call above/below it.

New to excel so apologies in advance if this does not make sense.

Comment: 16 Dataset and 112 vars in excel ? ..

Comment: Yes? But i have put the variables row wise. i need to see if the variable names match

Comment: Would be better if you show your code ..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the problem is that you have a column of cells (say A2:A10 assuming row 1 is a header) containing text and you want highlight the duplicates with and * in the next column (B) - you have a couple of options. If your column of text items are sorted you could use the following formula which checks a cell against the cells above and below:

```
=IF(OR(A2=A1,A2=A3),"*","")
```

If they are not sorted then you could use a formula that checks each cell with every cell below it. This just highlights the first found duplicate, like so:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A3:$A$10,A2)>0,"*","")
```

If you are likely to add or remove items from your list and you want to make the formula flexible enough to handle this, then use this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(A3,0,0,COUNTA(A:A),1),A2)>0,"*","")
```